# Error while configuring odoo in cents 6.6

Tags: odoo, centos6.6

When i am trying to install odoo through yum i am getting the following error.

Finished Dependency Resolution
Package: odoo-8.0_20150617-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@base)
            python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (test)
               python(abi) = 2.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Steps i followed mentioned below.

1. installed the pstgresql 9.4.4
2. updated the python 2.6 to 2.7
3. Configured odoo repository
4. tried to install odoo using yum install odoo

I have updated the python also.

## python --version

Python 2.7.6

Can any one help me to solve this issue

Comment: you have to install python from source to separate directory, then create virtual environment and install all dependencies inside it.

Comment: Better to install CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed odoo by using this document 
https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/

Answer (score 0):

correct way is to creating virtual environment.

```
yum -y install wget gcc zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libffi-devel libxslt libxslt-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel openldap-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel openjpeg-devel libtiff-devel git libpng libXext libz.so.1 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 curl cabextract

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.9.tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.7.9.tgz
cd Python-2.7.9
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make
make altinstall

wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | /usr/local/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 pip virtualenv
```

this is what you must have on centos 6.6

```
[root@server ~]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@server ~]# yum install python
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror1.babylon.network
 * epel: mirror1.babylon.network
 * extras: mirror1.babylon.network
 * updates: mirror1.babylon.network
Package python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

this is the full guide i found:
https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/

Comment: When i check python version i could see that 2.7
[root@server ~]# python --version
Python 2.7.9

Comment: really?     `Finished Dependency Resolution Package: odoo-8.0_20150617-1.noarch (odoo-nightly) Requires: python(abi) = 2.7 Installed: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (@base) python(abi) = 2.6 Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (test) python(abi) = 2.6 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`do you understand this message??? :)

Comment: I didn't understand this message.but i have installed python 2.7.
Now i am trying to install the odoo using 
https://odootricks.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/installing-odoo-8-on-centos-6-with-virtual-python-install/